# c# OpenGL GLUT: Glut.glutReshapeFunc() isn't being called on Glut.glutReshapeWindow()

Tags: c#, opengl, glut

I've been following a series of YouTube tutorials to learn the basics of using OpenGL (and GLUT) in C# to render 3D shapes. The current video I've reached is here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PPHNwhEXDQU

In my code below, the callback function OnReshape() is not being called when I programatically (or manually) resize the window using Glut.glutReshapeWindow(1280, 720) in the OnKeyboardUp() callback function. (At least, I'm pretty sure it's not being called - a breakpoint placed inside the OnReshape() function is never reached.) This means that when I toggle out of fullscreen mode (by pressing the 'f' key), the window is not resized to 1280 x 720 and the projection_matrix is not updated so the model is no longer in the centre of the window.

I've tried running this on both my PC and laptop and the results are the same, so I think it's something inherent to the code or the way I've set the project up.

I can't think why this isn't being called :/
Can anybody help? It would be much appreciated...

Here is my full code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Tao.FreeGlut;
using OpenGL;

namespace OpenGL_Tutorial_1
{
    class Program
    {
        private static int width = 1280, height = 720;
        //how to render everything
        private static ShaderProgram program;
        //to store vertices of the cube
        private static VBO<Vector3> cube;
        //to store cube uv values
        private static VBO<Vector2> cubeUV;
        //to store the elements (which order to render) of the above vertices
        private static VBO<int> cubeElements;
        //cube texture
        private static Texture cubeTexture;
        //vertex normals
        private static VBO<Vector3> cubeNormals;
        //stopwatch to get a rotation per frame
        private static System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch watch;
        //rotation angle
        private static float angle;
        //do we want lighting?
        private static bool lighting;
        //do we want auto-rotation?
        private static bool autoRotate;
        //do we want fullscreen mode?
        private static bool fullscreen;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //initialise glut .dll
            Glut.glutInit();
            //double buffering to stop any flickering (i.e. stop seeing the screen being drawn, just the result)
            //septh buffer ensures that closest object is drawn, prevents double- or over-drawing
            Glut.glutInitDisplayMode(Glut.GLUT_DOUBLE | Glut.GLUT_DEPTH);

            //create window itself
            Glut.glutInitWindowSize(width, height);
            Glut.glutCreateWindow("OpenGL Tutorial");

            //what to do each frame render
            Glut.glutIdleFunc(OnRenderFrame);
            //dispose of all junk objects in shader program
            Glut.glutCloseFunc(OnClose);
            //callback funtions to detemine keyboard presses
            //key pressed
            Glut.glutKeyboardFunc(OnKeyboardUp);
            //key released
            Glut.glutKeyboardUpFunc(OnKeyboardDown);
            //callback function called when window is reshaped
            Glut.glutReshapeFunc(OnReshape);

            //Enable depth testing
            Gl.Enable(EnableCap.DepthTest);

            //autorotate initially
            autoRotate = true;
            //no fullscreen mode initially
            fullscreen = false;
            //lighting initially
            lighting = true;

            //assign VertexShader and FragmentShader functions to the shader, so it knows how to render pixels
            program = new ShaderProgram(VertexShader, FragmentShader);

            //use shader program
            Gl.UseProgram(program);
            //set the values of the VertexShader matrices
            //setting up how object is projected, and limits of how far away from screen to render
            program["projection_matrix"].SetValue(Matrix4.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(0.45f, (float)width / height, 0.1f, 1000f));
            //setting up a camera located at 0,0,10, looking at 0,0,0, along Y direction
            program["view_matrix"].SetValue(Matrix4.LookAt(new Vector3(0, 0, 10), Vector3.Zero, Vector3.UnitY));
            //light direction vector from front
            program["light_direction"].SetValue(new Vector3(0, 0, 1));
            //set lighting on or off initially
            program["enable_lighting"].SetValue(lighting);
            //set autorotate initially
            autoRotate = true;
            //no fullscreen mode initially
            fullscreen = false;

            //load texture
            cubeTexture = new Texture("iceTexture.jpg");

            //create cube vertices TL, TR, BL, BR
            //coordinate system is such that xz is horizontal plane with y goint up, so vertical vector is 0,1,0
            cube = new VBO<Vector3>(new Vector3[] {
                new Vector3(1, 1, -1), new Vector3(-1, 1, -1), new Vector3(-1, 1, 1), new Vector3(1, 1, 1),         //top
                new Vector3(1, -1, 1), new Vector3(-1, -1, 1), new Vector3(-1, -1, -1), new Vector3(1, -1, -1),     //bottom
                new Vector3(1, 1, 1), new Vector3(-1, 1, 1), new Vector3(-1, -1, 1), new Vector3(1, -1, 1),         //front
                new Vector3(1, -1, -1), new Vector3(-1, -1, -1), new Vector3(-1, 1, -1), new Vector3(1, 1, -1),     //back
                new Vector3(-1, 1, 1), new Vector3(-1, 1, -1), new Vector3(-1, -1, -1), new Vector3(-1, -1, 1),     //left
                new Vector3(1, 1, -1), new Vector3(1, 1, 1), new Vector3(1, -1, 1), new Vector3(1, -1, -1)          //right
            });
            //map each cube vertex to some point on the texture (the 4 corners of the texture)
            cubeUV = new VBO<Vector2>(new Vector2[] {
                new Vector2(0, 0), new Vector2(1, 0), new Vector2(1, 1), new Vector2(0, 1),
                new Vector2(0, 0), new Vector2(1, 0), new Vector2(1, 1), new Vector2(0, 1),
                new Vector2(0, 0), new Vector2(1, 0), new Vector2(1, 1), new Vector2(0, 1),
                new Vector2(0, 0), new Vector2(1, 0), new Vector2(1, 1), new Vector2(0, 1),
                new Vector2(0, 0), new Vector2(1, 0), new Vector2(1, 1), new Vector2(0, 1),
                new Vector2(0, 0), new Vector2(1, 0), new Vector2(1, 1), new Vector2(0, 1)
            });
            //assign vectors to each vertex of each face
            //each face has 4 vertices with normals in the same direction (normal to plane)
            cubeNormals = new VBO<Vector3>(new Vector3[] {
                new Vector3(0, 1, 0), new Vector3(0, 1, 0), new Vector3(0, 1, 0), new Vector3(0, 1, 0),
                new Vector3(0, -1, 0), new Vector3(0, -1, 0), new Vector3(0, -1, 0), new Vector3(0, -1, 0),
                new Vector3(0, 0, 1), new Vector3(0, 0, 1), new Vector3(0, 0, 1), new Vector3(0, 0, 1),
                new Vector3(0, 0, -1), new Vector3(0, 0, -1), new Vector3(0, 0, -1), new Vector3(0, 0, -1),
                new Vector3(-1, 0, 0), new Vector3(-1, 0, 0), new Vector3(-1, 0, 0), new Vector3(-1, 0, 0),
                new Vector3(1, 0, 0), new Vector3(1, 0, 0), new Vector3(1, 0, 0), new Vector3(1, 0, 0)
            });
            //assign cube vertex order
            cubeElements = new VBO<int>(new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23 }, BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer);

            //start stopwatch
            watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();

            //runs the rendering window
            Glut.glutMainLoop();

        }

        private static void OnClose()
        {
            cube.Dispose();
            cubeUV.Dispose();
            cubeElements.Dispose();
            cubeTexture.Dispose();
            cubeNormals.Dispose();
            program.DisposeChildren = true;
            program.Dispose();
        }

        //what happens when each frame is rendered
        private static void OnRenderFrame()
        {
            //calculate time since last frame
            watch.Stop();
            float delta = (float)watch.ElapsedTicks / System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.Frequency;
            watch.Restart();

            //increment rotation angle if auto-rotation is delected
            if(autoRotate) angle += delta;

            //create viewport - where stuff is seen
            Gl.Viewport(0, 0, width, height);
            //clear previous frame info, colout and depth buffers 
            Gl.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit | ClearBufferMask.DepthBufferBit);

            //use shader program
            Gl.UseProgram(program);

            //use texture in program
            Gl.BindTexture(cubeTexture);

            //rotate and translate cube
            program["model_matrix"].SetValue(Matrix4.CreateRotationY(angle/2) * Matrix4.CreateRotationX(angle) );

            //set lighting on or off
            program["enable_lighting"].SetValue(lighting);

            //pass program variables to shader program variables
            Gl.BindBufferToShaderAttribute(cube, program, "vertexPosition");
            Gl.BindBufferToShaderAttribute(cubeUV, program, "vertexUV");
            Gl.BindBufferToShaderAttribute(cubeNormals, program, "vertexNormal");
            Gl.BindBuffer(cubeElements);

            //draw the cube
            Gl.DrawElements(BeginMode.Quads, cubeElements.Count, DrawElementsType.UnsignedInt, IntPtr.Zero);

            //swap working and display buffers to prevent tearing - set up in double buffering earlier
            Glut.glutSwapBuffers();

        }
        //called when a key is pressed
        private static void OnKeyboardDown(byte key, int x, int y)
        {
            //if escape key is pressed (value 27), exit main loop
            if (key == 27) Glut.glutLeaveMainLoop();
        }

        //called when a key is released
        private static void OnKeyboardUp(byte key, int x, int y)
        {
            //if l key is pressed, toggle lighting value
            if (key == 'l') lighting = !lighting;
            //space key to toggle autorotation
            else if (key == ' ') autoRotate = !autoRotate;
            //f to toggle fullscreen mode
            else if (key == 'f')
            {
                //toggle value
                fullscreen = !fullscreen;
                if (fullscreen) Glut.glutFullScreen();
                else
                {
                    Glut.glutPositionWindow(0, 0);
                    //calls OnReshape when this is done
                    Glut.glutReshapeWindow(1280, 720);
                }
            }
        }

        private static void OnReshape(int width, int height)
        {
            //when window is resized, set new height and width, and recalculate projection_matrix as this relies on screen size
            Program.width = width;
            Program.height = height;

            //use shader program
            Gl.UseProgram(program);
            //setting up how object is projected, and limits of how far away from screen to render
            program["projection_matrix"].SetValue(Matrix4.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(0.45f, (float)width / height, 0.1f, 1000f));

        }

        //tells gpu how to manipluate all vertex data it receives
        //runs once per vertex in most cases
        //written in GLSL (OpenGL Shading Language)
        public static string VertexShader = @"
            #version 130

            in vec3 vertexPosition;
            in vec3 vertexNormal;
            in vec2 vertexUV;

            out vec2 uv;
            out vec3 normal;

            uniform mat4 projection_matrix;
            uniform mat4 view_matrix;
            uniform mat4 model_matrix;

            void main(void)
            {
                //if model has rotated, the normals will rotate too
                //rotate normals by model_matrix, extract xyz components and normalize to length 1
                normal = normalize((model_matrix * vec4(vertexNormal, 0)).xyz);

                //pass uv texture value thorough this shader
                uv = vertexUV;

                //find actual screen coordinates of vertices
                gl_Position = projection_matrix * view_matrix * model_matrix * vec4(vertexPosition, 1);
            }
        ";

        //Does the actual shading
        //takes the color from the vertex shader and linearly interpolates between vertices
        public static string FragmentShader = @"
            #version 130

            //light direction
            uniform vec3 light_direction;

            //sampler samples the texture (image supplied)
            uniform sampler2D texture;

            //toggle to enable lighting
            uniform bool enable_lighting;

            in vec2 uv;
            in vec3 normal;

            out vec4 fragment;

            void main(void)
            {
                //calculate the diffuse lighting of each vertex based on its angle to the light direction
                float diffuse = max(dot(normal, light_direction), 0);

                //ambient lighting intensity
                float ambient = 0.3f;

                //actual lighting value of each vertex
                //only display lighting if it is toggled on
                float lighting = (enable_lighting ? max(diffuse, ambient) : 1.0);

                //texture2D function samples the image at the uv coordinates provided, and renders the colour
                //lighting modifies the colour by scaling it between 0 and 1
                //only colour values of the sample (not the alpha value) must be modified in intensity
                vec4 sample = texture2D(texture, uv);
                fragment = vec4(sample.xyz * lighting, sample.a);
            }
        ";
    }
}
```

Comment: So your actual problem is that the window isn't resizing? For me that doesn't sound as if it has something to do with `OnReshape`.

Comment: Have you tried to call `glutReshapeWindow` first and then `glutPositionWindow`?

Comment: @BDL Yeah I've just tried what you suggested, hasn't changed anything unfortunately. The window isn't resizing, but I'm pretty sure the callback is the problem. I've just added a Console.WriteLine() to the OnReshape() function and sure enough, nothing gets written.

Comment: I guess `OnReshape()` isn't called because the window doesn't resize. So you should most probably be looking into why that happens. If it resizes, then you can think about why `OnReshape` isn't called.

Comment: This is the confusing thing really, because OnReshape() isn't called, even when I manually resize the window. So I know the window is being resized (because I'm doing it manually), which should fire off the OnReshape(). Anyway, thanks for the help - hopefully someone has run into this issue before.

Comment: I've been reading this: https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node23.html which says that the system is free to do what it wants with window sizing - maybe this has something to do with it? Either way, I'm not sure how to check that a request to reshape a window has been granted.